# Changes to markup files not getting picked up in wicket project

Tags: websphere, wicket, reload, websphere-6.1, hotdeploy

When I change a html file in my wicket project and reload the page the changes don't get automatically picked up. I have to republish to pick up the changes. Changes to java files get picked up without any problems. I am running a wicket 1.4 project on a websphere 6.1 server.

So far I have tried the following steps

1. Validated that reloadingEnabled="true" is set in the ibm-web-ext.xmi file
2. Checked all reload settings in the admin console to make sure reloading is not disabled
3. Tried to run jvm in develpment mode
4. Validated that the changed markup file gets copied to the output folder by the ide
5. Tried the settings recommended in [this article](http://www.wicketframework.org/faqs.html#how-reload-changed-markup-files).

but the markup files are still not getting reloaded.

I am suspecting the wicket markup cache to be the problem but shouldn't the changes in step 5 have resolved the problem?
Any ideas on what might cause this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wicket manages its own resource reloading - which, in my experience, works flawlessly. Note that since Wicket does it all itself, and does not rely on any container to do this, the problem is likely a mismatch between where Wicket is **looking** for the resources and where the resources you change **actually** are.

I experienced the same symptom when I was working in RAD/Eclipse with Jetty and had "Build Automatically" turned off. I'd change resource files in src/main/resources and not see them change when I refreshed. The reason was because Jetty was actually loading copies of the file below the target/ directory. Eclipse (and m2eclipse) automatically keep those folders in sync when "Build Automatically" is enabled, but of course does not when disabled.

If that's not the cause, I'd try turning the Wicket logging to DEBUG level and look to see if Wicket logs which directories it is watching for changes. My guess is that will be different from the directories in which you are making your changes.